# Clearing the diagnal plots of the plotmatrix

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Consider the following matrixplot

```
randdata = rand(1000,3);
[~,ax] = plotmatrix(randdata)
```

Now for example if i want to clear the diagnol plots , I am using the following method

```
ClrIndx = find(eye(size(randdata,2)))

ClrIndx =

     1
     5
     9

cla(ax(ClrIndx))
```

but the diagnol plots arent being cleared , just to be sure i compared the axes handles

```
double(ax)

ans =

    0.0029    3.0029    6.0029
    1.0029    4.0029    7.0029
    2.0029    5.0029    8.0029

double(ax(ClrIndx))

ans =

    0.0029
    4.0029
    8.0029
```

Which confirms i have got the right axes handles but still the `cla()`command does not clear the diagnol plots , what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that there's a lot of axes magic going on with `plotmatrix`. Looking at the help, it turns out that it uses multiple kinds of auxiliary invisible axes. You need to clear the last one:

```
[~,~,~,~,pax]=plotmatrix(randdata);
cla(pax(LinearClrIndex));
```

where the indices should be linear: in case of a 5x5 matrix plot, `pax` will be a 5-element array.

If you want to delete the axes, not just clear it, you need the second output as well:

```
randdata = rand(5)
[~,ax,~,~,pax]=plotmatrix(randdata);
delete(pax(2));
delete(ax(2,2));
```

This will leave a gaping hole full of emptiness in the (2,2) position.

Comment: and I just noticed that you have to clear the through px index by index by a loop `cla(px(2))` clears the second plot in the diagnol but if i do `cla(px)` it doesnt clear all